# fetch returns 401, but able to view the JSON fine through a browser window

Tags: .net, iis, fetch

Fetch is returning 401 errors when trying to read a controller. However, I am able to navigate to the controller URL and see the json fine. The website has anonymous access disabled, and windows authentication enabled on the root. The issue occurs on localhost or live.

**Fetch Code**

(Polyfill https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch)

```
fetch("/api/letters")
    .then((data) => {
        return data.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
            items: json
        });
    });
```

**LettersController**

```
'----------------------------------------------------
'GET: api/letters
'----------------------------------------------------
'.
'.
'.
Function GetLetters() As IHttpActionResult

    Return Ok(db.Test.Where(Function(X) X.username = Modules.User.Username)

End Function
```

**User Module**

```
Public ReadOnly Property Username As String
    Get
        Return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding credentials: "include" to the fetch options solved it.

```
fetch("api/letters", { credentials: 'include' })
        .then((data) => {
            return data.json();
        })
        .then((json) => {
            this.setState({
                items: json
            });
        });
```

Comment: More information on fetch request options can be found here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options